# Load table elements into the Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I want load table elements (from database) to combobox. Unfortunately, the following code does not load items

```
<ComboBox   Margin="209,283,51,160" Name="Nazwa_menagera" ItemsSource="{Binding GetMenagerzyComboboxItems}"
                      SelectedValuePath="Key"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=IdMenagera, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
```

`private ATMAEntities atmaEntites;`

```
  public IQueryable<ComboboxKeyAndValue> GetMenagerzyComboboxItems()
            {
                return
                    (
                        from menagerzy in atmaEntites.Menagerzy
                        select new ComboboxKeyAndValue
                        {
                            Key = menagerzy.idMenagera,
                            Value = menagerzy.nazwa + " " + menagerzy.imie + " " + menagerzy.nazwisko,
                        }
                    ).ToList().AsQueryable();
            }
```

```
public class ComboboxKeyAndValue
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You'll probably need to include more of your XAML code. Do you have `DataContext` set anywhere?

Comment: I can't. I have this same code in other program and this work correctly :) I have only   public int IdMenagera
        {
            get
            {
                return _IdMenagera;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_IdMenagera != value)
                {
                    _IdMenagera = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(() => IdMenagera);
                }

            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to methods, it must be a property. And you also can't bind to IQueryable (as far as I know at least).

Some small changes that might get it working for you (given that you have the DataContext correctly set up):

```
public IEnumerable<ComboboxKeyAndValue> MenagerzyComboboxItems
{
    get
    {
        return
        (
            from menagerzy in atmaEntites.Menagerzy
            select new ComboboxKeyAndValue
            {
                Key = menagerzy.idMenagera,
                Value = menagerzy.nazwa + " " + menagerzy.imie + " " + menagerzy.nazwisko,
            }
        ).ToList();
    }
}
```

and changing you ItemsSource binding to

```
ItemsSource="{Binding MenagerzyComboboxItems, Mode=OneWay}"
```

For a better user experience you should probably look into retrieving your data asynchronously instead and publish them for the view using `INotifyPropertyChanged` and/or via an `ObservableCollection`.